# Exclude a few words from a simple regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm categorizing a few folders on my drives and I want to weed out low quality files using this regex (this works):

```
xvid|divx|480p|320p|DivX|XviD|DIVX|XVID|XViD|DiVX|DVDSCR|PDTV|pdtv|DVDRip|dvdrip|DVDRIP
```

Now some filenames are in High Definition but still have DVD or XviD in their filenames but also 1080p, 720p, 1080i or 720i. I need a single regex to match the one above but exclude these words 1080p, 720p, 1080i or 720i.

Comment: I don't get what exactly your problem is. Could you provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this

```
^(?!.*(?:1080p|720p|1080i|720i)).*(?:xvid|divx|480p|320p|DivX|XviD|DIVX|XVID|XViD|DiVX|DVDSCR|PDTV|pdtv|DVDRip|dvdrip|DVDRIP)
```

This will match on your search strings, but fail if there is also `1080p|720p|1080i|720i` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use two regex's

one to find if it matches

```
1080p|720p|1080i|720i
```

Then if it **doesn't**, that is no match is found for the above, check for matches:

```
xvid|divx|480p|320p|DivX|XviD|DIVX|XVID|XViD|DiVX|DVDSCR|PDTV|pdtv|DVDRip|dvdrip|DVDRIP
```

Regular expressions don't support inverse matching, you could use negative look-arounds but for this task I wouldn't say they're appropriate. As you check for all the cases of `1080p-divx`, you put a negative look ahead, however it doesn't catch `divx-10bit-1080p`, you couldn't achieve this in a *simple* regex.

Comment: I cant use 2 regexes sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<pre><?php
$subjects = array('Arrival of the train at La Ciotat station.avi',
                  'Gardenator II - multi - DVDrip - 720i.mkv',
                  'The adventures of Roberto the bear - divx.avi',
                  'Tokyo’s Ginza District - dvdrip.mkv');

$pattern = '~(?(DEFINE)(?<excl>(?>d(?>vd(?>rip|scr)|ivx)|pdtv|xvid|320p|480p)))
             (?(DEFINE)(?<keep>(?>[^17]+?|1(?!080[ip])|7(?!20[ip]))))
             ^\g<keep>*\g<excl>\g<keep>*$  ~ix';

foreach($subjects as $subject) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $subject)) echo $subject."\n"; }
```

The main interest is to avoid to test a lookahead on each character.